# SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost'?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am using XAMPP and phpmyadmin to make a site on the localhost. I keep getting the message: 
SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'players'

All privileges ARE granted to the user. When I hover over the user in phpmyadmin, it says 'includes all privileges except grant'.

What do I do? I am relatively new to this.

Comment: "_What do I do?_" ? You post your code here.

Comment: what about on the specific table itself? `grant all on *.* to...` is different than `grant all on specificdb.*`